# Excel Search if Word is somewhere in Column A and also in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to check if any of the entrys in column A contain somewhere the same word as the entry in column B ?

I want to check if words appear double somewhere in the columns and if they are present the words are supposed to be marked in red and the word which is double is supposed to be written in column C.

Unfortunately, I am not really good with excel and hardly know anything about VBA, so I would be grateful for complete solutions.

Again in short:

- In column A, there is a text or sentence with words and numbers in each cell
- In column B, there is a text or sentence with words and numbers in each cell, the words in column B can also be found somewhere in column A.
- In column C the word which are double somewhere in column A and B should be shown. Optimal would be a color highlighting of the cells / word which contain a duplication.

**Edit**

I am adding a picture here to show what i mean. I think the text is not that clear.

[image]

Comment: Well, you could start with FIND() to work on each column, combine the result to evaluate if both are true. All of the tasks you list would probably be better under vba... Have a search on here to see what bits of code exist doing things similar.

Comment: use conditional formatting with a formula COUNTIF(range, criteria) > 1. Range being entire column A, criteria being your cell in column B

Comment: I tried COUNTIF(range, criteria) > 1 but for this to work i need to have the exact same text in both cells, but i am look for single words. I edited my question with a picture to clearify my question.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using two columns for your answer but if I work out one formula for everything will update the answer for now this will give you what you expecting the formula to get the duplicates

```
  =COUNTIF($A$1:$B$7,B2)>1
```

this formula looks at column A cell 1 to column B cell 7 you can change that to meet your requirements. Then B2 is the value being counted so if your data start at 1 you put that formula on your first cell and change that to reference the cell being evaluated and drag to other cells the formula the answers to this will be true or false. True if the value is duplicate. The next formula on the next column will be the one that copies the duplicate value.

```
=IF(G2=TRUE,B2,FALSE)
```

for highlighting you can simple use conditional formatting hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your reply but i am look for all words in column b to be searched by. i edited my question with a picture.